# Product Name is not showing on product detail page

Tags: product, magento2.3

Product name is showing on product listing but when I clicked to view the specific product details it's not showing product name all other things. I use setup: upgrade and index: reindex and cache: flush many time but same result.

See Product Detail Image Below

[image]

See Admin Panel Image

[image]

Comment: I guess that it is theme issue..

Comment: @AmitBera Bro I am using Porto theme

Comment: In chrome right click on the page and inspect element and look through the source code you may have a stray display none in your theme or a div in the wrong place

Comment: @DavaGordon Product Title div not coming in code

Comment: Id suggest checking error logs to see if there are any errors if not then put your site into developer mode and seeing if any errors show on the product page in the bootstrap.php file add error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); and disable cache to do this. see if anything shows up that way

Comment: Product name is not showing, if you have done changes related to css for page-title class or you have removed "page.main.title" block from layout. Can you please check this for your theme?